# Selecting from multiple tables, huge result

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select items from 2 tables, it should return 2 results, but I am getting more than a 1000:

```
$sqlH = 'SELECT * FROM sheikh_tbl, wall';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR (srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%")';
```

Thanks for explaining me the query issue

EDIT: UNION ALL is used instead of UNION

[The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: And what? What do you expect from us?

Comment: You are to start with using an OR statement. The results that matches will be returned for any of these columns. You may want to use and instead of OR?

Comment: The 1000 results that you get back - are they valid? 
Are you expecting to get back 2 results based on your data, OR do you want to limit the result to only give you back 2 results?

Comment: use inner join better to match up only record and that cause cross join of each row from one table to another.

Comment: you probably meant to join the tables?  what's the purpose of wall?  It's never referenced in the query

Comment: I do not mean JOIN, and it should return 2 results, if I separate the tables, I will get 1 result on each table, but if I combine queries, I am getting a lot of results

Comment: Include your Table Structure for both table??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kritner has provided an answer, I just wanted to clarify for your understanding:

A comma separated list of tables is deprecated join syntax, when no join criteria is used to filter the join, you get a cross join/cartesian product:

Table1:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

Table2:

```
ID
4
5
6
```

So this query:

```
SELECT *  FROM Table1,Table2
```

Returns:

```
1,4
1,5
1,6
2,4
2,5
2,6
3,4
3,5
3,6
```

Since your `WHERE` criteria was a list of `OR` statements, you got all records back because at least one of the criteria matched a record from each table.  You either need to use a proper join, or as Kritner suggests, `UNION` two unrelated queries to get one result set.

Comment: (I felt your explanation was what I was trying to convey, but you did a much better job at it) :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a join condition. Without that, each row from the first table is coupled with each row from the second table.

Assuming both tables have an `id` column that should match:

```
$sqlH = 'SELECT * FROM sheikh_tbl, wall';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE sheikh_tbl.id = wall.id';
$sqlH .= ' AND (shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR (srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"))';
```

Or better yet, you should use the more modern explicit `join` syntax:

```
$sqlH = 'SELECT * FROM sheikh_tbl';
$sqlH .= ' JOIN wall ON sheikh_tbl.id = wall.id';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR (srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%")';
```

Comment: There is no join, I would like to select items from both tables, that have NOT any relation between them

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty confusing... but based on the comments something like this might do ya:

```
$sqlH = 'SELECT * FROM sheikh_tbl';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR (srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%")';
$sqlH .= 'UNION SELECT * FROM wall';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR (srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%")';
```

this is making an assumption that your schema is the same between the two tables, your "," implies a join which you stated should not be occuring.  The above query is the same, just separated out by a union.  Might help, but posting your schema and why you expect 2 results would be of more use.

Answer (score 0):

I used the UNION as suggested above:

```
$sqlH = 'SELECT shk_fname FROM sheikh_tbl';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sqlH .= ' UNION SELECT srub FROM wall';
$sqlH .= ' WHERE rub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
```

So they are 2 queries, result is 2 (which is wrong, I added a new insert), and if I seperate them, I got result is 3 (wich is right)