# 2 queries and pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am having 2 queries, I could not use UNION, see problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723744/selecting-from-multiple-tables-huge-result)

so, I was forced to use 2 separate queries:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM sheikh_tbl, wall';
$sql1 .= ' WHERE shk_fname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sql1 .= ' OR shk_mname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
$sql1 .= ' OR shk_lname LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
```

number of results for this is 14

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM wall WHERE srub = "Sawtiyat" AND wtitle LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
```

number of results for this 32

Now, time for pagination, I set 10 results per page, in total I have now 46, which means 5 pages, so witch query should I use to proceed for pagination LIMIT $start, $perPage

Thanks guys

Comment: Why can't you use a `UNION`? All I see in the question/answer you posted is that you can't use a `JOIN`. I see your answer you posted about trying `UNION` and it only returned 2 rows instead of 3. That is because [`The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result.`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). You could use `UNION ALL` to get all rows, even if there is a duplicate. Then you could easily do a `LIMIT` on the `UNION ALL` query

Comment: Don't use `LIMIT` for pagination, do it on the PHP side. _OR_ make an effort and use a single query.

Comment: there are two way to pagination .. one is on client side another one is handle through backend databse query

Comment: @Sean: appreciated, works great
Muhammad Ali: did not get it, could you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723744/selecting-from-multiple-tables-huge-result)

by using UNION ALL instead of UNION, so now the pagination will get simple.

Thanks guys